# the formulas for upper and lower integrals for absolute value of bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, riemann-integration

> Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be bounded. Prove that 
>   $$\left|\int_a^{b^-}f(x)dx\right| \leq \int_a^{b^-}|f(x)|dx.$$
>
> Give an example showing that an analogue nonequality does not valid for the lower integral.
>
> P.S.  $\int_a^{b^-}$ means the upper integral.

Actually I tried to use the definitions and I think the inf and sup in the definitions of integrals make the difference in this case however I did not get that.

Appreciate any comment or solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example for the lower integral. Let $f(x)=0$ if $x =\frac p q$ with $(p,q)=1$ and $q$ even, $f(x)=-1$ if $x =\frac p q$ with $(p,q)=1$ and $q$ odd, $f(x)=1$ if $x$ is irrational. The RHS is $0$ whereas LHS is $1$.

For the  upper integral use the fact that $|\sup_{[c,d]} f(x)| \leq \sup_{[c,d]} |f(x)|$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for short solution.